# Stronger visual divider between answers

Tags: support, design

A nitpick but with the new format, when I'm reading answers, I keep seeing the answer below as a comment. I scroll down and I get the realisation "oh it's an answer, not a comment".

To give an idea of what I mean:

[image]

(Screenshot from [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-can-we-promote-better-writing-skills-in-academic-education).)

... my immediate visual reaction is that "1. HAVE them write ..." starts a comment under the answer, not a new answer.

---

Or is it just me?

Comment: I noticed the exact same thing, but I couldn't put my finger on why I was doing that. Good eye.

Comment: The figure you show might not be the best example, because of the offset in the text caused by the numbered list.

Comment: @aeismal, indeed. But I'm a computer scientist and I'm interested in worst case analysis! :)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to reinforcing the visual divider (making it bold would do wonders) would be to have the questions and answers alternate between white and perhaps the beige in the logo/header bar. Optionally the question itself could have a 3rd distinct colour. This makes delineation (e.g. whether you are reading a very long question/comment string or the start of an answer) immediately visually obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I'm noticing it too, and would like some better/bolder visual seperation - I was comparing this site to CrossValidated, now that I've had some time to use the new site design extensively, and I am noticing that the "beige on slightly lighter beige" color scheme, while soothing, is letting my eye slide down the page without registering a transition from Question to Answer, and between answers.